# SAP RFC heavy upload - 3MB txt file produces 150MB upload

Tags: traffic, large-data-volumes, saprfc

I have a problem with startRFC.exe that produces much bigger network-traffic than required. startRFC has 3 parameters = 3 internal tables = 3 CSV files. Total size of these files that are sent to SAP is 3MB, but it takes 15minutes and totally is uploaded 150MBs.

Has anyone experienced this?

Comment: So we found that SAP returns error CPIC = error in communications.

Comment: What function module are you calling? What are its parameters and how are you measuring the 150MB?

Comment: It is our FM and it has only 3 parameters = 3 csv files = internal tables (each row 13000 characters and 1000 - 10000 rows). Data transfer is measured by standard NetMeter and also by our server admin tools.

Comment: Can you paste the signature of the function module?

Comment: You mean to describe the FM? I don't know how it works, I do not have access to it. I am looking for potential problems in communication between SAP (RFC) and my computer. Now we reduced number of characters on one row from 13000 to 2500 and the error CPIC persists, but speed and traffic was better.

Comment: Are you able to see what data is being transferred when the RFC call is being made? I wonder if `startrfc` is translating it to XML before doing the call, which would explain the size increase. I can't see an option to `startrfc` to influence that though.

Comment: POSSIBLE SOLUTION: So it seams that our traffic 150MB was correct although filesize was only 3MB. Problem is that if there is in startRFC defined row-length 1300 (for an Internal Table), startRFC automatically padds all rows with spaces to the max-length. We had cca 6000 rows per 13000 characters = 78MB if 1 char = 1 byte. If 1 char = 2 bytes then 150MB is obvious result.

Answer (score 1):

POSSIBLE SOLUTION: So it seams that our traffic 150MB was correct although filesize was only 3MB. Problem is that if there is in startRFC defined row-length 1300 (for an Internal Table), startRFC automatically padds all rows with spaces to the max-length. We had cca 6000 rows per 13000 characters = 78MB if 1 char = 1 byte. If 1 char = 2 bytes then 150MB is obvious result